# Laplace Equation PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$U_{XX}+U_{YY}=1 $$ in the annulus $ a<r<b$ with u vanishing on both parts of the boundary r=a and r=b

What I have done is that $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0$ has only 0 due to the fact that u is vanishing on r=a and r=b and by th and that u has the maximum principle.

So, I think I have to find the unique solution of $U_{XX}+U_{YY}=1 $

and it is the same as finding the unique solution of $u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_{r}+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta \theta}=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is not ok, since in general $0\neq1$. The quickest way to find the solution is as follows.

Assume that the solution has rotational symmetry, then  $u(r)$ (with $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$) satisfies the ODE
$$ u''+\frac{1}{r}u'(r)=1 \tag{1}$$
and boundary conditions $u(a)=0$, $u(b)=0$. General solution of the corresponding homogeneous ODE is $u_h(r)=C_1+C_2\ln r$. It is also very easy to guess a particular solution of the nonhomogeneous equation: $u_{nh}(r)=\frac{r^2}{4}$. Therefore, the general solution of (1) is 
$$ u(r)=u_h(r)+u_{nh}(r)=C_1+C_2\ln r+\frac{r^2}{4}.$$
Taking into account the boundary conditions to determine $C_1$, $C_2$, one finds
$$ u(r)=\frac{r^2\ln\frac{b}{a}-b^2\ln\frac{r}{a}-a^2\ln\frac{b}{r}}{4\ln\frac{b}{a}}.\tag{2}$$
But now if we consider the function $w=U-u$, it will satisfy the *homogeneous* Laplace equation and *homogeneous* boundary conditions. Therefore $w=0$ and the solution (2) is unique.